# Use non continuous program with Supervisord

Tags: c, flask, raspberry-pi, supervisord

I have a program that supervisord/flask is running that is only about 80 lines of code and doesn't need to be ran continuous. Just a single instance, is there a way to set that in the config so it knows that? It runs fine, It just gives me an error in the log when that's not really an error, its what I want.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Werkzeug, you can take a look at this snippet http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/67/ to create a shutdown method and call it after your first request.

```
from flask import request

def shutdown_server():
    func = request.environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown')
    if func is None:
        raise RuntimeError('Not running with the Werkzeug Server')
    func()
```